# Why do I always get 404 error on Magento 1.9 when using rewrite on url with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I am trying to perform rewrite on a cms page which has some simple phtml code in it. I am trying to rewrite

`www.website.com/blogs/?title=test`

to

`www.website.com/blogs/test`

I have tried adding it to the Magento admin section for rewrite rules and I have also tried by adding it to `.htaccess` file but I always got a 404 error using below code or variations of it.

It seems like it can't post other controller code to see my code and goes straight to 404 page. Thanks.

```
RedirectMatch 301    /blogs/?title=test    /blogs/test     
RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/]+)/?$ blogs/?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You can use the default rewrite in admin and create new route instead of editing htaccess

Answer (score 0):

This condition will rewrite the request `/blogs/?title=test` to `/blogs/test`. Just add it in your `.htaccess` file right after `RewriteEngine on`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blogs/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=test$
RewriteRule .* /blogs/test? [L,R=301]
```

or more general for any `title` parameter:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blogs/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /blogs/%1? [L,R=301]
```